# Select2 dropdown on disabled mode

Tags: jquery, jquery-select2

I have the following issue:

[Fiddle Link](https://jsfiddle.net/hitesh1208patel/Lkzpo8h1/4/)

```
<select id="select2" style="width:250px">
  <option value=""></option>
  <option value="option 1">Option 1</option>
  <option value="option 2">Option 2</option>
  <option value="option 3">Option 3</option>
</select>

<input id="disableBtn" type="button" value="Disable" />

<input id="enableBtn" type="button" value="Enable" />
```

While select box is disabled, the drop down still pops up if spacebar is hit after focus on select box.

Following is the js code:

```
$('#select2').select2({placeholder: 'Select an option',minimumResultsForSearch: 'Infinity'});
$('#disableBtn').on('click', () => {$('#select2').attr('disabled', 'true');});
$('#enableBtn').on('click', () => {$('#select2').removeAttr('disabled');});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think there is an issue on **select2** jQuery component.
So here is a snippet which adopt a workaround to achieve your goal:

```js
$('#myselect').select2({
  containerCssClass: 'mysel-con',
  placeholder: 'Select an option',
  minimumResultsForSearch: 'Infinity'
});

$('#disableBtn').on('click', ()=>{
  $('#myselect').select2('enable', false);
  $('.mysel-con').css('pointer-events', 'none');
});

$('#enableBtn').on('click', ()=>{
  $('#myselect').select2('enable');
  $('.mysel-con').css('pointer-events', '');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.6-rc.0/css/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.6-rc.0/js/select2.full.min.js"></script>

<select id="myselect" style="width:250px">
  <option value=""></option>
  <option value="option 1">Option 1</option>
  <option value="option 2">Option 2</option>
  <option value="option 3">Option 3</option>
</select>

<input id="disableBtn" type="button" value="Disable" />

<input id="enableBtn" type="button" value="Enable" />
```

`containerCssClass` option is used to define a css class used as a jQuery selector for select2 container.

So adding CSS property `pointer-events`: `none` to this container the goal is reached.

Pay attention to use **select2.full** version (see. https://github.com/select2/select2/tree/master/dist/js).

[Fiddle updated.](https://jsfiddle.net/beaver71/vrjrsptj/)

Comment: It worked. thank you. however pointer-events property is not supported in IE 10 and lower. Can you please suggest something for that ?